# What is the complexity for this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm learning big O notation and solving some problems, since i'm very new to this subject, i would like to know the complexity of this algorithm.

```
function findSum(arr,value){
    const set = new Set();
    for (let val of arr) {
      set.add(val);
    }
  
    const res = [];
    
    for (let val of set) {
      const target = value - val
      if (set.has(target)) {
        res.push(val, target);
        break;
      }
    } 
    return res.length > 0 ? res : false;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down:

`set.add()` is an `O(1)` operation, hence the first part is clearly `O(n)`, with `n` being the length of `array`.

`set.has()` is also `O(1)` (the whole point of hash-based data structures is to enable constant time lookups), and so is `res.push()` (appending to an array). That means that the second part (traversing the set) is also `O(n)`.

Therefore the whole function is `O(n)`.